# In docker container can`t find already installed pip packages

Tags: image, docker, pip

I’m trying to setup a Docker image running python3.6.   My code relies on some packages, so i build a basic image using pip install all necessary packages.
The basic image Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:7

RUN curl -o /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo http://mirrors.aliyun.com/repo/Centos-7.repo
RUN yum install -y python3 python3-pip python36-devel python36-setuptools; yum clean all

COPY requirements.txt ./
# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt -i http://mirrors.aliyun.com/pypi/simple/ --trusted-host=mirrors.aliyun.com

CMD ["bash"]
```

I named this basic image as myrepo:5000/base-py.
I build a test image FROM myrepo:5000/base-py. 
Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM myrepo:5000/base-py

# pip install Django
RUN pip3 install Django==2.1.2  -i http://mirrors.aliyun.com/pypi/simple/ --trusted-host=mirrors.aliyun.com

LABEL kemp.app="noded"
CMD ["bash"]
```

**In this new test  container i can`t find some packages which was installed in basic image!**

I use wagoodman/dive:latest tool to analysis this test image，it shows the packages already in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages directory. **But when i in the container, only Django in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages.**
[dive analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Moa7.jpg)

```
[root@vmhost ~]# docker run --rm test ls /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
django
Django-2.1.2.dist-info

[root@vmhost ~]# docker run --rm myrepo:5000/base-py ls /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
aiozmq
aiozmq-0.7.1.dist-info
async_timeout
async_timeout-3.0.1.dist-info
attr
attrs-19.3.0.dist-info
certifi
certifi-2020.4.5.1.dist-info
chardet
```

I don't know where the problem is.
what should I do to get all pip packages in new image`s container? Thanks in advance!

Comment: After building the image, did you tag it as `myrepo:5000/base-py` because you are using that while building the second docker image

Comment: yeal, i taged base-py as myrepo:5000/base-py, they are same image.